# Spring Data GemFire Region entry expiration (Time-To-Live) error

Tags: spring, spring-boot, gemfire, spring-data-gemfire

I have a *Spring Data GemFire* Region that's configured using annotations below:

```
@TimeToLiveExpiration(timeout = "100", action = "INVALIDATE")
@PartitionRegion(name = "blockedIPCache")
class BlockedIpEntityType { ... }
```

My application is a *Spring Boot* application and I used the following annotations to configure SDG:

```
@PeerCacheApplication
@EnableGemfireCaching
@EnableCachingDefinedRegions(clientRegionShortcut = ClientRegionShortcut.LOCAL, serverRegionShortcut = RegionShortcut.LOCAL)
@EnableStatistics
@EnableExpiration
@EnableEntityDefinedRegions(basePackageClasses = {...})
@EnableGemfireRepositories(basePackages = {...})
class GemFireConfiguration { ... }
```

All I want is to insert an object using a *Spring Data GemFire* Repository and after awhile the entry will be invalidated.

But, I face this Exception when I start my application...

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot set idle timeout when statistics are disabled.
    at org.apache.geode.internal.cache.AbstractRegion.setCustomEntryIdleTimeout(AbstractRegion.java:1157) ~[geode-core-9.1.1.jar:?]
    at org.springframework.data.gemfire.config.annotation.ExpirationConfiguration$ExpirationPolicyMetaData.configure(ExpirationConfiguration.java:511) ~[spring-data-gemfire-2.0.6.RELEASE.jar:2.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.gemfire.config.annotation.ExpirationConfiguration$1.postProcessAfterInitialization(ExpirationConfiguration.java:160) ~[spring-data-gemfire-2.0.6.RELEASE.jar:2.0.6.RELEASE]
...
```

This happens exactly when Spring tries to autowire my Repository related to the Region configured above.

So what I'm doing wrong? And, is there a way to enable Region statistics using Java configuration or Annotations?

Note: Using *Spring Data GemFire* **2.0.6**, *Spring* **5.0.5**, *Spring Boot* **2.0.1** used in the project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out, you did not do anything wrong.  Unfortunately, you stumbled across a bug(!), for which I have already filed [SGF-747](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SGF-747) and fixed.  I am sorry for the inconvenience this issue may have caused you.

We are planning a *Spring Data* **Lovelace M3** (Milestone 3) release tomorrow (**Thursday, 5/17, CET**).  The release schedule is visible from [Spring Release Calendar](https://spring-calendar.cfapps.io/).  All dates are tentative.

As such, you could try the new *Spring Data for Pivotal GemFire* (SDG) **Lovelace** bits (i.e. 2.1.0.M3) with the fix.  SDG 2.1.0. should work just fine with *Spring Boot* **2.0.1/2.RELEASE** and *Spring* **5.0.5/6.RELEASE**.

However, if you are expecting to get GA bits for SDG containing this fix, then you will have to wait for the next *Spring Data* **Kay** *Service Release* (**Kay SR8**), or the *Spring Data for Pivotal GemFire* **2.0.8** *Service Release*.  I am backing porting this fix.

Unfortunately, there is not another *Spring Data* **Kay** *Service Release* (i.e. **Kay SR8**) planned until probably around **July 2nd** or **3rd**, right after *Spring Framework* **5.0.7** is released on **Monday, July 2nd** and just before *Spring Boot* **2.0.3** is released on **Wednesday, July 4th**, which is usually when we plan *Spring Data* *Service Releases*.  Also, know that *Spring Boot* **2.0.x** is [based on](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/2.0.x/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-dependencies/pom.xml#L158) *Spring Data* **Kay**, but should work just fine with SD **Lovelace** too, as I mentioned previously.

In the meantime, I will try to think of workaround where the convenience of the Annotations (e.g. `@EnableEntityDefinedRegions`) can still be used.  I will post the workaround in [SGF-747](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SGF-747).

I see that you specified the `clientRegionShortcut` attribute in the `@EnableCachingDefinedRegions` annotation but have declared your application to be a `@PeerCacheApplication`.  While there is no harm in doing so, the `clientRegionShortcut` attribute is useless in this case.  Likewise, the `serverRegionShortcut` attribute would have no meaning if you are application were a `@ClientCacheApplication` instead; something to keep in mind.

Lastly, I wanted to let you know that the SDG `@EnableStatistics` annotation does not have the effect you probably think it does.

Specifically, SDG's [`@EnableStatistics`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/gemfire/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/gemfire/config/annotation/EnableStatistics.html) annotation is concerned with enabling Pivotal GemFire's statistics "sampling" as explained [here](http://gemfire.docs.pivotal.io/95/geode/managing/statistics/how_statistics_work.html), which is configured by doing [this](http://gemfire.docs.pivotal.io/95/geode/managing/statistics/setting_up_statistics.html), as also explained in the SDG `@EnableStatistics` annotation Javadoc, as well as referenced in the SDG [Reference Guide](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/geode/docs/current/reference/html/#bootstrap-annotation-config-region-expiration).

The "statistics enabling" that ultimately needs to happen is by [setting](http://gemfire-95-javadocs.docs.pivotal.io/org/apache/geode/cache/RegionFactory.html#setStatisticsEnabled-boolean-) the Region's [`staticsEnabled` attribute property](http://gemfire-95-javadocs.docs.pivotal.io/org/apache/geode/cache/RegionAttributes.html#getStatisticsEnabled--) when configuring and creating the Region (e.g. "blockedIPCache").

That is exactly what the `@EnableExpiration` annotation will indirectly guarantee  now, with the fix in [SGF-747](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SGF-747), without the need to `@EnableStatistics`.

Anyway, I hope this all makes sense and helps.

Regards,
John

Comment: Thank you Mr. John for the fast response, and for the further explanation on `@EnableSatistics`. I can upgrade to Lovelace M3 for now and after the Kay SR8 release I'll switch back to kay. Thanks again you saved my day :)

Comment: You are welcome, and this just in... https://spring.io/blog/2018/05/17/spring-data-lovelace-m3-released